# How to change settings for Fn keys on Magic Keyboard when used with MacBook Air?

Tags: keyboard

I use a Magic Keyboard with my MacBook on a stand. The <kbd>Fn</kbd> keys on the Magic Keyboard only use as standard <kbd>F1</kbd>, <kbd>F2</kbd>... keys don't work as controls, i.e. I can't use them to adjust volume or screen brightness. <kbd>Esc</kbd> key and lock keys work fine.

In standard keyboard settings, this requires unticking the "Use F1, F2, etc. keys as standard function keys" but my settings only adjust the built-in MacBook's keyboard not the connected Magic Keyboard.